# where to store static arrays in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios

I am Android developer and am trying to make a my first iPhone application. As it is done in Android; we store static arrays in arrays.xml, where can we store such static arrays in iPhone application development on iPhone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Removed the objective-c tag as this is not an objective-c question so much as it pertains to the runtime environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xml` too, but the easiest way probably is to use a `plist` file and use `NSDictionary` to parse it. You can create `plist` files using Xcode. You can also store arrays in `plist`s.

There is plenty of resources on the Internet on how to do this, for example [here](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=64679).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use that array in all the classes you have then just add one Header (.h) file to your project and declare array inside it. Import this file to your class and you can use the array there.

And if you are using it in one time then u can do it as follow:

```
NSArray *arrName = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:@"val1",@"val2",@"val3",nil];
```

You can store 'n' number of values. Just make sure last 'nil'.